# Listview with different view in each row

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I want to implement something like this
[list photo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83thmzwbj558kbz/Photo%207-20-16%2C%205%2020%2018%20PM.jpg?dl=0)
this list contains different controls in each row like radio button,spinner etc.

Comment: removed resources recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your custom listview adapter add override these methods

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return super.getViewTypeCount();
}
```

and

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

replace return super.getViewTypeCount(); with the number of view that you intend to use, then in your getView method you can modify you view from

```
if(convertView == null)
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
```

to:

```
if(convertView == null)
   {
  if(getItemViewType(position) == 0)
     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
}else{
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, null);}
```

Note: This question must have been answered and you are supposed to post the code you tried earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Create an adapter and in the getView() implement an algorithm that handles the right layout and content

**Example**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        private List<String> names;

        public SimpleTextAdapter(Context context, List<String> names) {
            super(context, R.layout.custom_row_simple_text, names);
            this.names = names;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View customView = null;
            if(position == 0){
              customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1, parent, false);
              //Get Views from layout_1
              TextView tv = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
              tv.setText(names.get(position));
            }else if(){
              customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_2, parent, false);
              //Get Views of layout_2
            }else{
              customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_3, parent, false);
              //_______,,_________
            }
            return customView;
        }
    }
```